# Calculate integral $2\int_{0}^{1}e^{-400(x-0.3)^2}\sin(h\pi x) dx$ where $h \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, wave-equation

I'm solving the wave equation
$$
\begin{cases}
  \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - v^2 \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} =0, &(x,t) \in (0;1) \times \mathbb{R}^+_{*},\\
  u(t,0) =u(t,1) =0, & t \in  \mathbb{R}^+_{*},\\
  u(0,x) = e^{-400(x-0.3)^2}, &x\in (0;1),\\
  \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}(0,x) = 0, & x\in (0;1).
 \end{cases}
$$

By using the Fouriers series to solve, the solution takes form (corrected):
\begin{align*}
 u(t,x) = \sum_{h=1}^{\infty}a_h\cos(hv\pi t)\sin(h\pi x), 
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
 a_h = 2\int_{0}^{1}e^{-400(x-0.3)^2}\sin(h\pi x) dx.
\end{align*}
But I'm having trouble calculating this integral,
$$a_h = 2\int_{0}^{1}e^{-400(x-0.3)^2}\sin(h\pi x) dx. $$
with $h \in \mathbb{N}, h \ge 1$.
Could someone please help me calculate this integral?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

With
$$f(x)\mapsto\exp \left(-k^2 (x-\xi )^2\right)\sin (\pi  h x)$$

we get the antiderivative

$$F(x)\mapsto\int f(x) \, dx=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{1}{4} \pi  h \left(\frac{\pi  h}{k^2}+4 i \xi \right)} \left(e^{2 i \pi  h \xi } \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\pi  h}{2 k}+i k (x-\xi )\right)+\text{erfi}\left(\frac{\pi  h}{2 k}-i k (x-\xi )\right)\right)}{4 k}$$

Now we compute the definite integral
$$I_1=\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx=F(1)-F(0)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{1}{4} \pi  h \left(\frac{\pi  h}{k^2}+4 i \xi \right)} \left(-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{\pi  h}{2 k}+i k (\xi -1)\right)-e^{2 i \pi  h \xi } \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\pi  h}{2 k}-i k (\xi -1)\right)+\text{erfi}\left(\frac{\pi  h}{2 k}+i k \xi \right)+e^{2 i \pi  h \xi } \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\pi  h}{2 k}-i k \xi \right)\right)}{4 k}$$

The final result then is
$$a_h=2 I_1 |_ {k=20,\xi=\frac{3}{10}}=\frac{1}{40} i \sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{\pi  h (\pi  h+480 i)}{1600}} \left(-e^{\frac{3 i \pi  h}{5}} \text{erf}\left(6+\frac{i \pi  h}{40}\right)+\text{erf}\left(14+\frac{i \pi  h}{40}\right)+\text{erf}\left(6-\frac{i \pi  h}{40}\right)-e^{\frac{3 i \pi  h}{5}} \text{erf}\left(14-\frac{i \pi  h}{40}\right)\right)$$

with erf(z) the error function.

Animation of $u(t,x)$:

[image: Imgur]